# Selenium Python Element.click not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to mimic user actions on a site to download a csv file.

The "Get Data" button generates the link "download file in csv format" when I do it manually but it doesn't work with the automation.

I get an exception saying the link was not found.

Here are the things that i tried:

- Adding explicit waits to have enough time for the page to load. Didn't work.
- Adding explicit waits between click on get_data and before clicking on download link. Didn't work.
- Tried different ways of the clicking the "get data" button ie

  ```
   i) get element by xpath and then click.

   ii) driver.wait_until(....    driver.find_element.. and not(@disabled). to make sure the button is    not disabled. didn't work    
   iii) Added asserts to make sure the    button is displayed and enabled.
  ```

** Here is anomaly which I don't understand.
I went through the html file to understand how its working and there is javascript which validates the input data. So I guess the "get_data" wont work if the input data is incorrect.

So I tried to display the text after entering the symbol "SBIN" via sendkeys by

print(driver.find_element_by_id("symbol").text)

and this prints empty. Not sure if this is problem.

Would be really grateful for a solution as it would save me ton of manual effort is getting stock data.

Here is the video with the changes suggested by KunduK
youtube.com/watch?v=hBjjfPIeSCQ&feature=youtu.be

Here is the website.
https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm

Here is the python script for the webdriver.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm")
        driver.find_element_by_id("dataType").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Get historical data for:'])[1]/following::option[3]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("symbol").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("symbol").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("symbol").send_keys("SBIN")
        driver.find_element_by_id("series").click()
        Select(driver.find_element_by_id("series")).select_by_visible_text("EQ")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Select series :'])[1]/following::option[15]").click()
        Select(driver.find_element_by_id("dateRange")).select_by_visible_text("24 Months")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='For past:'])[1]/following::option[8]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("get").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Download file in csv format").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Download file in csv format").click()
```

to below code:

Wait element to be clickable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  //Explicit Waits to wait for ExpectedCondition
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Download file in csv format'))).click()
```

Comment: I dont think the issue is with the wait. Clicking on get_data element is supposed to generate the link to download the file. However I dont the link even if were to wait for 20 secs. I think the click on get_data isn't doing what its supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following xpath to click on csv file link.

secondly to get the value from input element you have to use `element.get_attribute('value')`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm")
driver.find_element_by_id("dataType").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Get historical data for:'])[1]/following::option[3]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("symbol").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("symbol").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("symbol").send_keys("SBIN")
# To get the value from input text
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#symbol'))).get_attribute(
    'value'))
driver.find_element_by_id("series").click()
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("series")).select_by_visible_text("EQ")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Select series :'])[1]/following::option[15]").click()
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("dateRange")).select_by_visible_text("24 Months")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='For past:'])[1]/following::option[8]").click()
# driver.find_element_by_id("get").click()    

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "get"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Download file in csv format']"))).click()
```

Comment: I tried this. There is a timeout from WebDriverWait. The issue here I think is the click on get_data element is not doing whats its supposed to do. The click on get_data should generate the link but it doesn't when i use the script. It works if I were to do it manually.

Comment: This shouldn't be.I have run that code before posted and it worked.

Comment: @SujithHiremath : try the updated code I have added `webdriverwait` there as well.Let me know how it goes?

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back. Will give this shot by evening and will definitely get back to you. (at work and cannot test this out.)

Comment: Still doesnt work. Maybe its got to do with chrome version/OS. Here the link the screen recording https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBjjfPIeSCQ&feature=youtu.be. I have added a print before and after click on the get_data button.The after print is never seen. I am using chrome version 79.0.3945.117on windows 10. running the webdriver using pycharm. I dont whats causing the issue.

Comment: Can you please let me know whats your chrome version, OS, python version and IDE if any?